# Regular expression outputting extra text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have created a regular expression to find dates like 2 January. However, my regex is also outputting the year i.e. 2 January 2007. I am not sure why it is doing that. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

My Code:

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f_input, open('file2.txt','w') as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    dict_month_name =['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']
    dict_month_prefix =['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']


    for line in csv_input:
        rx = r'\b[0-9]\s+(?:{month_prefix}|{month_name})\b'.format(
        month_prefix = "|".join(dict_month_prefix),
        month_name = "|".join(dict_month_name))
        x = re.findall(rx, line[3], re.I)
        if len(x) != 0:
            csv_output.writerow([line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]])
```

Comment: This code does not output anything. Can you post the code which is outputting the year?

Comment: Where is the year? There is totally no year at all in your code.

Comment: Your code never even looks at the result of the `re.findall` (except for its length), so why are you worried about matching the year?

Comment: *my regex is also outputting the year* – no it is not. If the regex matches, you (not the regex!) write out the original text. Nothing changes, nothing gets added.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my post now with the entire code.

Comment: This question is still impossible to answer. We don't know what your csv data looks like. We don't know what the input and output of that `re.findall` is. We don't even know what the problem is, because that regex definitely doesn't "output" (whatever that means) a year.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex looks like it won't match anything at all, try something like this:

```
(\d+)\s+(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|etc)
```